# EVAL: undefined function X

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I keep getting some random errors while trying to call my function that has to return
the level of a node from a binary tree.

This is my method

```
(defun nodeLevel(x index l)
    (cond
        ((null l) nil)
        ((equal (car l) x) index)
        ((equal (cadr l) 1) (nodeLevel ( x (+ index 1) (cddr l))))
        ((equal (cadr l) 2) (nodeLevel ( x (+ index 1) (cddr l))))
        (t nodeLevel(x (+ index 1) (cddddr l)))
    )
)
```

This is how i call it

```
(nodeLevel  'D '0 '(A 2 B 0 C 2 D 0 E 0) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have extra parentheses. When you call a function, the entire call goes in parens, but the arguments don't get their own set. You've written

```
(nodeLevel (x (+ index 1) (cddr l)))
```

What you probably meant was

```
(nodeLevel x (+ index 1) (cddr l))
```

Comment: I removed the unecessary parentheses and now i get COND: variable NODELEVEL has no value. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: You made a similar typo on the "else" line (the final `cond` condition).